# Pass more than one parameters with jQuery.post

Tags: php, jquery, amcharts

I'm using amCharts and as pointed in the tutorial here:
https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/saving-exported-chart-image-server/

this is the way to save the data from the export to your web server instead of downloading it for the client:

jQuery:

```
jQuery.post( "save.php", {
              imageData: encodeURIComponent( data )
            }
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$data = urldecode($_POST['imageData']);
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
file_put_contents('image.png', $data);
?>
```

And this works perfectly fine. However, what if I wanted to pass another paramater in addition to 'imageData'? What would the syntax be for both PHP and jQuery? I've tried numerous things but every time the other parameter appears blank in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$.post("save.php",{        
       data1:"This is data1",
       data2:"This is data2",
       data3:"This is data3"
    },
    function(dataComingFromSaveDotPhp){
       //you can optionally create a function here to handle PHP page's output
       alert(dataComingFromSaveDotPhp); //alerts save.php's output, shown below
    }
);
```

And you can use those in php like this:

```
$data1=$_POST["data1"];
$data2=$_POST["data2"];
$data3=$_POST["data3"];

echo $data1; //Output: "This is data1"
echo $data2; //Output: "This is data2"
echo $data3; //Output: "This is data3"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can't say I've tried this but could you explain how exactly I could use the variables in PHP if I post them this way?

Comment: It still doesn't work. The variables appear blank. :(

Comment: I've edited the code again, can you try with new one.

Comment: OK, I've got some progress but it still doesn't work fully. If I get the variable like this: $data1=$_POST["data1"]; and then do something like this : file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/test.txt', $data1); it creates the .txt file successfully and writes the data inside of it. However the variable is still blank when I echo it in PHP. How can I convert it so it shows properly when echoed?

Answer (score 0):

Ehi!

You can try something like this! :)

Javascript

```
jQuery.post( "save.php", {
          imageData: encodeURIComponent( data ),
          variable1: 123,
          variable2: "hello!",
          variable3: true,
        });
```

PHP

```
<?php
$data = urldecode($_POST['imageData']);
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
file_put_contents('image.png', $data);

$variable1 = $_POST['varible1'];
$variable2 = $_POST['varible2'];
$variable3 = $_POST['varible3'];
?>
```

Bye! ;)

Comment: I've tried that and sadly it doesn't work. Variables 1, 2 and 3 appear null in PHP, as if no information was passed to them.

Comment: The code is correct, you may try to display the response printing the variables with PHP. Please check your code :)

Answer (score 0):

Success and error functions would help to identify the issue.

```
$.ajax({
       url: "save.php",
       data: {
          imageData: encodeURIComponent( data ),
          data2: 'image name'

       },
       type: 'post',

       success: function(xhr) {

        alert(xhr);
       },
       error: function(error) {

        alert(error);
       }
    });
```